# How can I make this rendezvous hashing code work?

Tags: c, algorithm, gcc, hash, distribution

Rendezvous Hashing is an algorithm which solves the same problem as consistent hashing:

> ...an algorithm that allows clients to achieve distributed agreement
>   on which site (or proxy) a given object is to be placed in.
>
> ---
>
> Rendezvous hashing has the following properties.
>
> 1. Low overhead: The hash function used is efficient, so overhead at the clients is very low.
> 2. Load balancing: Since the hash function is randomizing, each of the n sites is equally likely to receive the object O. Loads are uniform
>      across the sites.
> 3. High hit rate: Since all clients agree on placing an object O into the same site SO , each fetch or placement of O into SO yields the
>      maximum utility in terms of hit rate. The object O will always be
>      found unless it is evicted by some replacement algorithm at SO .
> 4. Minimal disruption: When a site fails, only the objects mapped to that site need to be remapped. Disruption is at the minimal possible
>      level, as proved in
>      [[1]](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/techreports/cse/96/CSE-TR-316-96.pdf).
>
> ---
>
> - [Wikipedia: Rendezvous hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing)

Fantastic. Now, I've implemented a modified version which maps sets of keys into bins [before](https://github.com/haneefmubarak/experiments/tree/master/rendezvous), and that appeared to work marvelously:

### sbins.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include <assert.h>

#include <math.h>

//#include <blake2.h>

#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))

#define NODES   20
#define KEYS    16777216
#define CSKIP   1048576

__uint128_t hashes[NODES]   = {0};
int count[NODES]    = {0};

static inline int rendezvous (__uint128_t *pool, uint64_t id) {
    register int x, bin = 0;
    register __uint128_t max = 0, cache;

    for (x = 0; x < NODES; x++) {
//      blake2 ((void *) &cache, &pool[x], &id, sizeof (cache), sizeof (pool[x]), sizeof (id));
        cache = pool[x] * ~id;
        max = MAX (max, cache);
        bin = max == cache ? x : bin;
    }

    return bin;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    assert (fread (hashes, sizeof (hashes[0]), NODES, stdin) == NODES);

    register int x, bin;
    for (x = 0; x < KEYS; x++) {
        bin = rendezvous (hashes, x);
        count[bin]++;
        if (!(x % CSKIP)) {fprintf (stdout, "%i\n", x);}
    }

    fputs ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", stdout);

    float avg = (float) KEYS / (float) NODES;

    float mad = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < NODES; x++) {
        fprintf (stdout, "Bin %i\t: %i\n", x, count[x]);
        mad += abs ((float) count[x] - avg);
    }

    fputs ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", stdout);

    fprintf (stdout, "avg: keys/bin\t= %f\n", avg);

    mad /= (float) NODES;
    fprintf (stdout, "mad: keys/bin\t= %f\n", mad);

    float moa = mad / avg;
    moa *= 100;
    fprintf (stdout, "mad / avg\t= %05.2f %%\n", moa);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `gcc sbins.c -lm` and run with `cat /dev/urandom | ./a.out`, it appeared to be distributing rather well:

```
1048576
2097152
3145728
4194304
5242880
6291456
7340032
8388608
9437184
10485760
11534336
12582912
13631488
14680064
15728640








Bin 0   : 838966
Bin 1   : 838596
Bin 2   : 839535
Bin 3   : 838835
Bin 4   : 839220
Bin 5   : 838759
Bin 6   : 838907
Bin 7   : 838903
Bin 8   : 838302
Bin 9   : 838726
Bin 10  : 838522
Bin 11  : 838034
Bin 12  : 839020
Bin 13  : 839334
Bin 14  : 838898
Bin 15  : 838905
Bin 16  : 838984
Bin 17  : 838753
Bin 18  : 838956
Bin 19  : 839061








avg: keys/bin   = 838860.812500
mad: keys/bin   = 235.500000
mad / avg   = 00.03 %
```

---

So far, so good. So a while later (AKA now), I actually needed to write code that used that. I knew I needed replicas, so I figured that I would simply store, sort, and return a list as opposed to always selecting the highest value. I ended up creating a similar set of routines, in two files, based on what I had written above, to accomplish this task:

### rendezvous.h (the header with the actual rendezvous code in it):

```
#pragma once
// adapted from
// http://git.io/pgkqvw
// (haneefmubarak/experiments/rendezvous)

//===   Includes

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//===   Structures

typedef struct {
    __uint128_t val;
    int bin;
} rdv;

//===   Special

#define SORT_NAME rendezvous
#define SORT_TYPE rdv
#define SORT_CMP(x, y) ((((rdv)x).val) - (((rdv)y).val))
#include "./deps/sort/sort.h"

//===   Functions

static inline int *rendezvous (__uint128_t *pool, uint64_t id, int nodes) {

    register int x;

    // store temporary results
    rdv *cache  = malloc (nodes * sizeof (rdv));
    if (!cache)
        return NULL;
    int *bin    = malloc (nodes * sizeof (int));
    if (!bin) {
        free (cache);
        return NULL;
    }

    // calculate for each server
    for (x = 0; x < nodes; x++) {
        cache[x].val    = pool[x] * ~id;
        cache[x].bin    = x;
    }

    // sort the results
    rendezvous_tim_sort (cache, nodes);

    // extract the results
    for (x = 0; x < nodes; x++) {
        bin[x] = cache[x].bin;
    }

    // cleanup
    free (cache);

    return bin;
}
```

and a test routine:

### tests/rendezvous.c (the test):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "../rendezvous.h"

#define NODES   20
#define REPFAC  4
#define KEYS    16777216
#define CSKIP   1048576

__uint128_t hashes[NODES]   = {0};
int count[REPFAC][NODES]    = {{0}};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    assert (fread (hashes, sizeof (hashes[0]), NODES, stdin) == NODES);

    register uint64_t x, y;
    register int *bin;
    for (x = 0; x < KEYS; x++) {
        bin = rendezvous (hashes, x, NODES);
        for (y = 0; y < REPFAC; y++)
            count[y][bin[y]] += 1;
        free (bin);
        if (!(x % CSKIP)) {fprintf (stdout, "%llu\n", x);}
    }

    for (x = 0; x < REPFAC; x++) {
        fputs ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", stdout);
        fprintf (stdout, "RepSet %llu\n", x);
        for (y = 0; y < NODES; y++)
            fprintf (stdout, "Bin %llu\t: %i\n", y, count[x][y]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### note: the file "sort.h" is from [github:swenson/sort](https://github.com/swenson/sort).

However, when compiling this file with `gcc rendezvous.c` and running it with `cat /dev/urandom | ./a.out`, the code seems to be failing EPICLY:

```
0
1048576
2097152
3145728
4194304
5242880
6291456
7340032
8388608
9437184
10485760
11534336
12582912
13631488
14680064
15728640








RepSet 0
Bin 0   : 0
Bin 1   : 16777216
Bin 2   : 0
Bin 3   : 0
Bin 4   : 0
Bin 5   : 0
Bin 6   : 0
Bin 7   : 0
Bin 8   : 0
Bin 9   : 0
Bin 10  : 0
Bin 11  : 0
Bin 12  : 0
Bin 13  : 0
Bin 14  : 0
Bin 15  : 0
Bin 16  : 0
Bin 17  : 0
Bin 18  : 0
Bin 19  : 0








RepSet 1
Bin 0   : 0
Bin 1   : 0
Bin 2   : 16777216
Bin 3   : 0
Bin 4   : 0
Bin 5   : 0
Bin 6   : 0
Bin 7   : 0
Bin 8   : 0
Bin 9   : 0
Bin 10  : 0
Bin 11  : 0
Bin 12  : 0
Bin 13  : 0
Bin 14  : 0
Bin 15  : 0
Bin 16  : 0
Bin 17  : 0
Bin 18  : 0
Bin 19  : 0








RepSet 2
Bin 0   : 0
Bin 1   : 0
Bin 2   : 0
Bin 3   : 16777216
Bin 4   : 0
Bin 5   : 0
Bin 6   : 0
Bin 7   : 0
Bin 8   : 0
Bin 9   : 0
Bin 10  : 0
Bin 11  : 0
Bin 12  : 0
Bin 13  : 0
Bin 14  : 0
Bin 15  : 0
Bin 16  : 0
Bin 17  : 0
Bin 18  : 0
Bin 19  : 0








RepSet 3
Bin 0   : 0
Bin 1   : 0
Bin 2   : 0
Bin 3   : 0
Bin 4   : 16777216
Bin 5   : 0
Bin 6   : 0
Bin 7   : 0
Bin 8   : 0
Bin 9   : 0
Bin 10  : 0
Bin 11  : 0
Bin 12  : 0
Bin 13  : 0
Bin 14  : 0
Bin 15  : 0
Bin 16  : 0
Bin 17  : 0
Bin 18  : 0
Bin 19  : 0
```

---

I tried to figure out what might be the cause of the problem. I even thought I might have a precedence issue or something with `count[y][bin[y]]++`, so I changed that, but to no avail. I think that the error is in `rendezvous.h`, but at this point I've mostly run out of ideas and haven't a clue.

Ideally, the output of the second program should be evenly distributed, similar to the first program. I can't find where the single bin is the only one being filled though.

---

So how can I get the program to work properly? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you write `bin = rendezvous (hashes, x, NODES);`, the result is that `bin` points to an allocation of size `NODES`. But then, you only read `REPFAC` values from `bin` before freeing it. That looks suspicious... Is it intentional?

Comment: @chrisculter yes, the idea is to get the lowest `REPFAC` number of values, because you usually have less replicas than you do server nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewire your comparator algorithm. Remember you're using **unsigned** values. Thus a comparator for this:

```
#define SORT_CMP(x, y) ((((rdv)x).val) - (((rdv)y).val))
```

will underflow if `x.val` is ever less than `y.val`. That, in turn, makes anyone assuming a standard "negative,zero,positive" outcome to dictate "less, equal, greater" is going to fail. They're ALL going to be "greater" (assuming the underflow returns a positive number; trap conditions not withstanding; technically its UB), or at best, "equal" if they're... well... equal.

I modified your code to use `qsort()` and a comparator of simply:

```
int cmp_rdv(const void *arg1, const void* arg2)
{
    const rdv* lhs = arg1;
    const rdv* rhs = arg2;
    return (lhs->val < rhs->val) ? -1 : (rhs->val < lhs->val);
}
```

then invoked it as you were, throwing out the old algorithm for:

```
// calculate for each server
for (x = 0; x < nodes; x++) {
    cache[x].val    = pool[x] * ~id;
    cache[x].bin    = x;
}

// sort the results
qsort(cache, nodes, sizeof(*cache), cmp_rdv);

// extract the results
for (x = 0; x < nodes; x++) {
    bin[x] = cache[x].bin;
}
```

The results are below, and likely what you're looking for (I cleaned up the wall-o-newlines and added some tabification for my own sanity).

```
0
1048576
2097152
3145728
4194304
5242880
6291456
7340032
8388608
9437184
10485760
11534336
12582912
13631488
14680064
15728640


RepSet 0
    Bin 0   : 838214
    Bin 1   : 838719
    Bin 2   : 838792
    Bin 3   : 839251
    Bin 4   : 838699
    Bin 5   : 838436
    Bin 6   : 838827
    Bin 7   : 839038
    Bin 8   : 839062
    Bin 9   : 838787
    Bin 10  : 839000
    Bin 11  : 838683
    Bin 12  : 839024
    Bin 13  : 838922
    Bin 14  : 838847
    Bin 15  : 839312
    Bin 16  : 838980
    Bin 17  : 838607
    Bin 18  : 839191
    Bin 19  : 838825


RepSet 1
    Bin 0   : 840405
    Bin 1   : 838603
    Bin 2   : 838612
    Bin 3   : 837891
    Bin 4   : 839700
    Bin 5   : 839559
    Bin 6   : 838918
    Bin 7   : 838834
    Bin 8   : 839128
    Bin 9   : 838711
    Bin 10  : 838930
    Bin 11  : 839856
    Bin 12  : 838654
    Bin 13  : 837914
    Bin 14  : 838665
    Bin 15  : 837965
    Bin 16  : 838278
    Bin 17  : 839167
    Bin 18  : 837817
    Bin 19  : 839609


RepSet 2
    Bin 0   : 838054
    Bin 1   : 838727
    Bin 2   : 838852
    Bin 3   : 839306
    Bin 4   : 837806
    Bin 5   : 838103
    Bin 6   : 838929
    Bin 7   : 837990
    Bin 8   : 837851
    Bin 9   : 838877
    Bin 10  : 838228
    Bin 11  : 837360
    Bin 12  : 839282
    Bin 13  : 840473
    Bin 14  : 839353
    Bin 15  : 840022
    Bin 16  : 840401
    Bin 17  : 838826
    Bin 18  : 840139
    Bin 19  : 838637


RepSet 3
    Bin 0   : 838545
    Bin 1   : 840246
    Bin 2   : 839210
    Bin 3   : 839441
    Bin 4   : 838555
    Bin 5   : 838835
    Bin 6   : 838539
    Bin 7   : 839562
    Bin 8   : 838275
    Bin 9   : 839164
    Bin 10  : 839194
    Bin 11  : 840005
    Bin 12  : 838463
    Bin 13  : 837821
    Bin 14  : 839498
    Bin 15  : 838393
    Bin 16  : 837376
    Bin 17  : 838632
    Bin 18  : 839393
    Bin 19  : 838069
```

I admittedly did *not* download the sort-source you mentioned only because I was lazy (why lie?). But I did check what the default is when you don't supply one, and it is:

```
#define SORT_CMP(x, y)  ((x) < (y) ? -1 : ((x) == (y) ? 0 : 1))
```

confirming my suspicion they need the standard less-then-zero/zero/greater-than-zero trio we're all used to providing. You can probably jus require your algorithm to match this format and it will give you what you seek.

Best of luck.

Comment: Awesome! I never thought to look there. Could you paste the whole source code to your version of the program in the post? Also, even though I'll be re-adapting the code, I have to ask: may I use your version of the code in my MIT licensed project?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to. `qsort` performance for something like this is horrible. the only difference between your code and what I worked was removing the 3rd-party sort stuff and making the modification listed here. Beyond that the source base is identical ([see here](http://pastebin.com/ADuCdTrt)). I just didn't want to clutter the answer with unneeded code.

Comment: @haneefmubarak heh. you don't need my go-ahead for that. It was a bug; thats all. still your code. I just showed you where the bug is. how you fix it is up to you =P. have you retooled your `SORT_CMP` to give the regular expected tertiary outcome? I'm curious if it worked out for you.

Comment: I've been on my phone this entire time. Lemme get back to my puter and see. I have a gcc intrinsic that should cut this.

Comment: Ended up using your `cmp_rdv()` function, made it `static inline` (so zero performance loss over a function call). I also tabbified the output similar to yours, as it looks neater. Finally, I adjusted the style of the stuff that I copied to fit in with the rest of the project.

Comment: @haneefmubarak very glad it helped. Best of luck on your project, and thanks for the alternate hash exposure. Always good seeing interesting code.

Comment: The project is located over at GitHub: https://github.com/haneefmubarak/sfDB5. I have a strong belief in giving credit where it is due - you can add your GH username and submit a pull request to https://github.com/haneefmubarak/sfDB5/edit/develop/CONTRIBUTORS and I'll merge it. NP for the exposure, I tend to find loads of useful but obscure algorithms haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60327/discussion-between-haneefmubarak-and-whozcraig).